# Filemaker Web Viewer Default Browser

Tags: browser, filemaker

Does the Filemaker Web Viewer use the default browser in your local settings?  I thought that this was the case, however I have changed by default browser to Firefox and Filemaker is still using Internet Explorer.  I am having problems with IE so I need to make a change.

Let me know if anyone has experience with this.  I have searched for articles on the web and found nothng.

Thanks

Comment: FileMaker's web viewer only works with internet explorer on windows and safari on the mac. Changing the default browser has no affect on FileMaker, it's an OS level change. 

It kind of makes sense when you think about it. FileMaker can't really guarantee that you will have anything aside from the default browser on your computer and they don't want to account for any idiosyncrasies  from other browsers. What's the issue you're having with IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileMaker web viewer uses IE on Windows and Safari on a Mac. Changing the default OS browser does not affect this.

On the other hand, changing the corresponding browser settings affects the behaviour of the web viewer, at least on Windows. E.g. security settings changed on the browser will be reflected in web viewer.